# No such file or directory error when running Docker container

Tags: python, oracle, docker, dockerfile

I have a REST Api for a Flask app with an Oracle database for which I use Oracle Instant Client.

I managed to run the app from my computer and it works fine and my task is to make a Docker file for this app. I don`t have much experience with Docker.

This is the Dockerfile that I have written

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim-buster

# Installing Oracle instant client
WORKDIR    /opt/oracle
RUN        apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip \
        && wget 
https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite- 
linuxx64.zip \
        && unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
        && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
        && cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* \
        && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci \
        && echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle- 
instantclient.conf \
        && ldconfig

WORKDIR    /app
COPY       . . 

EXPOSE     5000

CMD ["python", "/app/__init__.py"]
```

I use the following commands:

1. docker build - < Dockerfile
   And the Docker image build with no errors
2. docker run -d -p 5000:5000 (docker image id)
3. docker start -ai (docker container id)
   And I get this error: `python: can't open file '/app/__init__.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

The folder structure of the app on my computer is the following:
C:\Proiecte_python\Flask_Docker_App-Start\app
and in app are the instant oracle client the python file and the Dockerfile.

Can please someone help me because I think it`s something wrong in the Dockerfile CMD path or something like that. I have tried many variants but none work

Comment: why do you start python with `__init__.py`?

Comment: This is how I got my project from someone. My task is just to build a Dockerfile for it

Comment: i think the most part of dockerfile has been omitted, the `COPY` section.

Comment: If you run `docker build .` instead, does it work better?  Have you verified that the things you inspect are inside the container (for example, `docker run --rm 0123456789ab ls -l /app`)?

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your Dockerfile

```
CMD ["python", "/app/__init__.py"]
```

is equivalent to executing

```
python /app/__init__.py
```

The error you are getting is that the file **__init__.py** does not exist.

The lines

```
WORKDIR    /app
COPY       . .
```

Are telling your container to CD into the **/app** directory then copy all files from your **host** machine (Eg your physical machine) into the **/app** directory of the **container**. (the **COPY   . .** means to copy from the current directory of your host - eg the location you're running docker commands from - into the current directory of the container - **/app**).

It seems that as part of receiving the Dockerfile you should have also downloaded the **__init.py__** file and then the Dockerfile would have copied that into your container for you.

Alternatively you may have missed steps in your instructions where you were meant to write your own **__init.py__** file for testing.

Either way your solutions are to find the **__init.py__** file and put it into your current working directory ( C:\Proiecte_python\Flask_Docker_App-Start\app ) **and** ensure that you run your **docker build** and **docker run** commands from that same directory eg -

```
cd C:\Proiecte_python\Flask_Docker_App-Start\app
docker build <....>
docker run <....>
docker start <....>
```

Or your other solution is to go back to the instructions and ensure that you have created the python file and put it in the correct place.

As a very basic Flask/Docker tutorial see the below link

https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application